# How to flatten Entity Core many-to-many collections using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I can't figure out how to flatten a many to many collection. The entities are for the Identity tables created with Entity Framework Core. They contain navigation properties I added manually because the Identity entities don't include these by default (along with custom model builder code that is not shown)

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<long> {

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } = new List<AppUserRole>();

}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<long> {

    public virtual List<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } = new List<AppUserRole>();

}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long> {

    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }

}
```

This is the call in my repo:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AppUser>> GetAllWithRoles() 
{
    return await _dbSet
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
        .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

The above call returns back this structure:

```
[
{
    "firstName": "XXXX",
    "lastName": "YYYYY",
    "userRoles": [
        {
            "role": {
                "userRoles": [],
                "id": 1,
                "name": "xxx",
                "normalizedName": "xxxx",
                "concurrencyStamp": "1617fe40-77e2-46cb-9c1c-df597d09775c"
            },
            "userId": 1,
            "roleId": 1
        }
    ]       
}
]
```

what I want is this:

```
[
{
    "firstName": "Alex",
    "lastName": "Florin",
    "RoleName": "Role1",
},
{
    "firstName": "Alex",
    "lastName": "Florin",
    "RoleName": "Role2",
},
{
    "firstName": "Jon",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "RoleName": "Role1",
},
]
```

What I want is to flatten the collection. I have looked into SelectMany but I can't figure out how to use it with a many to many collection as I am fairly new to Linq. And I know the call function's type needs to be change to a viewmodel that matches my desired structure.

Automapper is another option as I'm using that to create the viewmodels for my simpler entities but I'm not clear how to set use that to flatten a many-to-many relationship

Comment: What do you want to flatten exactly? As is, your method return a IEnumerable, not a nested IEnumerable.

Comment: I'll edit the question to show what the method is returning back and what I want it to return instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The one issue is that it excludes any users with UserRoles = null but since all users are guaranteed to have at least one role in our system, it should be fine.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserEditorViewModel>> GetAllWithRoles() {

        return await _dbSet
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SelectMany(u => u.UserRoles)
            .Select(ur => new UserEditorViewModel {
                FirstName = ur.User.FirstName,
                LastName = ur.User.LastName,
                RoleName = ur.Role.Name
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to flatten exactly, to Select all Roles from User

```
users.Select(p => p.UserRoles.Role)
```

To Select all Users from Role

```
roles.Select(p => p.UserRoles.User)
```

Edit:

I think this exmaple will help you https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-2-hiding-as-ienumerable/

Your Model could look like this

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<long> {

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    private ICollection<AppRole> UserRoles{ get; } = new List<PostTag>();

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<string> RoleNames => UserRole.Role.Name

}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<long> {
    private ICollection<AppRole> UserRoles{ get; } = new List<PostTag>();

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<AppRole> Users => UserRole.User
}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long> {
    public long UserID{ get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }

    public long RoleID { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In EF Core an explicit join class/table is required for many-to-many relationships. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns

Comment: I edited the question to note that I added the migration properties so that they are included in the entities (they aren't included by Identity Framework core automatically. The table are generated correctly and I can get data out, I just need it flattened for displaying in a view

Comment: @Alex I edited  my answer the result would lock like this
[
{
    "firstName": "Alex",
    "lastName": "Florin",
    "RoleName": [ "Role1", "Role2" ],
},
{
    "firstName": "Alex",
    "lastName": "Florin",
    "RoleName": [ "Role1", "Role2" ],
},
{
    "firstName": "Jon",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "RoleName": [ "Role1", "Role2" ],
},
]

Comment: Thanks for that article. I'll look it over and try to implement it based on your answer. The output you listed is closer. I assume I could then user SelectMany to further flatten the result? What would that look like?

Comment: Converting the entities per the article and trying to make the model builder not break the Identity tables during migration is not working. I would much prefer trying to use LINQ to get the structure I was looking for.

Comment: @Alex Wouldn't you answer be the equivalent to query the AppUserRole table directly?